# Reminder Alert as in google for asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, service, alert

I need to show a message to the online users as alert popup like reminders in google calendar.

Can we use any background process like web service/windows service to achieve it?

Or is there any reliable way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

a lot of these apps that push messages to users are now using slightly different techniques to perform these pushes to browser. Studying comet and other techniques for keeping connections open to the browser will show you how these effects are efficiently achieved.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx (this is one of a few good articles on code project on the subject). hth

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about something like the Badge alerts here on StackOverflow, you can check out the blog post from Jeff Atwood about creating those 'background tasks'

[Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

Comment: This is really good example. I am able to call a method in global.asax every minute, but how can i execute a controller's action to get the information to show it as alert from global.asax